# what is the best way to create dynamic array of arrays of arrays

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic, hyperlink

I've got a problem. I need to create an array of arrays of arrays. I've read some articles about creating dynamic arrays in Java, but I'm not sure about what way I should choose.

The first one is to declare max possible size of each array `int arr[][][] = new int[10000][10000][10000];`, but in my case size of each array depends on size of another. I mean that each array can possibly has a size of max array and if I declare my array of arrays of arrays with this way it should take a lot of memory size.

The way is to use `ArrayList`. But I never used it before and I don't know the syntax of declaring `ListArray` of `ListArrays` and moreover `ListArray` of `ListArrays` of `ListArrays`. Also, I'm not sure about whether I should use it or not, because `ListArray` contains objects as elements and if I have an array like `[10000][100][20]` what is going to happen with my memory usage and other pc resources?..

The third problem is that in the best case scenario I'd like to have not objects or any other datatype variables as elements of array but links to other elements of another arrays element (I mean `arr[z][x][y] = @arrOfStr[i]`). I've never used links in Java though and I don't even know is it possible to use links as array elements and how should I declare my array.

So guys, I really need help in this because I've already broken my brain trying to resolve this problem with using minimum amount of pc resources.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: `List<List<List<Integer>>> dynamicAoAoA = new ArrayList<List<List<Integer>>>()`

Comment: What kind of data will you store in that data structure? If it's sparse, you might want to use some other data structure.

Comment: This is more a design problem than a programming problem. Maybe you need a `Data` class with the `int id`, `String link` attributes or something like that, then this `DataHolder` class (haven't found another name) that has `List<Data> lstData` attribute, then a `BigDataHolder` that contains a `List<DataHolder> lstDataHolder` attribute, and on and on...

Comment: I've never seen @links in Java ... Depending on the type of data you need to store, you could wrap the data before insertion into the array allowing you to use references to the same wrapped object in differenc cells of the array

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer:  this is probably a bad design in the first place, as it's pretty rare lists have to be nested this deep, or nested at all.  You probably want to flatten it out or use a `Set` or `Map`.  My guess is `Map` as what meaningful information do you get out of something being in the 3rd list?  Well if "3rd" is meaningful then a `map.add(3, myInt)` is a better way to go about accessing it.

Nonetheless the syntax is subtle enough so here's a working code sample.

> But i never used it before and i dont know the syntax of declaring ListArray of ListArrays and moreover ListArray of ListArrays of ListArrays.

So there's your problem.

```
List<Integer> array1 = new ArrayList<>();  //java 7 only
List<List<Integer>> array2 = new ArrayList<>(); 
array2.add(array1);
// ...
```

And so forth.

Sample code to create a 10x10x10 list and populate with some numbers:

```
List<List<List<Integer>>> list = new ArrayList<>();
int n = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    List<List<Integer>> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(list2);
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    List<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList();
    list2.add(list3);
        for(int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
            list3.add(n++);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza changed to add, push add whatever.

Comment: Not in Java `List` interface (maybe in another language or interface like [`Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html)?)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza there is no push in List, since I usually code an IDE and not in SO answers I don't mind whether to use `push`, `add` or some other method.  C++ STL `vector` uses `push_back` so I often think in this parlance.  add is correct: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(E)

Comment: I know what `push` means, just pointing out that **this is not C++**

Comment: I just want to reiterate @djechlin 's statement that a map may be an easier way to do this (optimization aside). It seems that this array might well be sparsely populated since the dimensions are dynamic, in which case a map is to be recommended even more highly.

Comment: well, guys thanks for you help. finally i desided to redesign structure of my function so at the and it should return array of maps. but sorry for stupid qustion - i dont know how to declare it. so can sombody say how declaration of array of maps should look like.

Comment: ooops, sorry! it seems i just found it. am i right Map<Integer, Integer>[] hmsi= new HashMap[n]?

Answer (score 0):

To be more explicit - do this:

```
import java.awt.Point;
```

`Point` is usually used in graphical cases and I suspect you just need a pair of integers.  You can [use Apache's immutable point class](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/ImmutablePair.html) or roll your own, if you do the latter remember to implement `hashCode()`.

```
Map<Point, Integer> map = new Hashmap<>();
```

There, one map, no lists.  I strongly suspect there is no reason in your code you need a list at all and you just want to be retrieving things by their coordinates.